# bat file loop stops too early

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I am using this piece of code to run a loop within a list of active processes to identify a process by name to change the priority.

```
TIMEOUT /T 1
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq java.exe" /fo table /nh') do set pid=%%j
echo %pid%
wmic process where processid=%pid% CALL setpriority 128
exit
```

My problem is I have more than one process called "java.exe" but I want them all to be effected by my code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) trap....

Comment: you didn't have a for loop block. The only command in the for loop is `set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq java.exe" /fo table /nh') do (
echo %%j
wmic process where processid=%%j CALL setpriority 128
)
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

This method will allow you to use the variable `pid`, but you will need to use delayed expansion.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq java.exe" /fo table /nh') do set pid=%%j
echo !pid!
wmic process where processid=!pid! CALL setpriority 128
exit
```

- The `setlocal` line is to allow cmd to process the variables at run-time, not phrase-time.
- `!` denotes to process the variable at run-time, not phrase-time.